# Have the Youtube iframes settings changed?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

Good morning,

I have a problem with the iframe embeed of Youtube.
Until yesterday, the player configuration parameters (showinfo, rel) worked correctly.
Today, however, I find that the players seem indifferent to these settings.
Has something changed?

thank you.